# PyCharm imports and code completion 

Tags: python, pycharm

Is it possible to configure PyCharm in the following way:

- Request auto-completion on any letter key press
- Complete on `space` press, instead of `enter`
- Request completion for modules not in `path`

I mean, configure it in VS-way.
Also, VS-like hotkeys will be amazing option

Comment: "I'm sick and tired of typing everything by hand and remembering all the functions names and signatures"  Then consider finding a new career.  If you think the IDE is helping you, perhaps you're missing the point.  Thinking is part of the programming task.  If you're successfully thinking through your code, then things are working.  "remembering all the functions" is part of your job as a programmer.  You have to know what they **mean**.  If you can do this, stop worrying about your IDE.  You're being successful, right?

Comment: @S.Lott "Thinking is part of the programming task." Yes, and I want to think about the _problem_ I'm solving, not stumbling around switching between viewing the API docs and the IDE.  "remembering all the functions" is NOT my job; knowing which ones to use is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm has reached to 2.7 now. you can customize your key mapping through "Kepmap" under "Settings" ->"Editor". I have a check, some of your requirement can be met by this.

Here is a reference link (http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html).
Hope above helpful to you.

Comment: thanks, I'm not doing any python coding as for now, but I hope your answer will help others

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro on this but I think you have to use the module name preceding the method you want to call. For example to call a function named doStuff in the settings module call settings.doStuff().

To call the methods directly you need to use "from settings import *". But I think this method is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official PyCharm feature [page](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/) you press Ctrl-Space to get auto completion. So for example if you type settings and then press Ctrl-Space I believe the IDE will present you with options.