# Simply passing False as F in python

Tags: python

How can I let python automatically know that F is False and T is True?
Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris=sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris.groupby("species").size().sort_values(ascending=F)
```

This fails. How can I make it work?

Comment: declare `F = False`

Comment: It is generally not recommended to take shortcuts like short variable, function or keyword names. Is there any specific reason why you want to use T and F instead of True and False which are much more explicit?

Comment: i advise you against bringing practices from different languages into others only because you are used to it, it will be confusing for other programmers that will work on the code after you, for example here IDE does the work for you - you write 'F' and then Tab and 'alse' is autocompleted, reading a code with explicit False is also much more convenient

Comment: @Dunatotatos I'm currently using spyder and find it inconvenient to keep filling everything. In R(RStudio), autocompletion is pretty great and saves me time. Is there any decent IDE so I can skip this declaring of variables?

Comment: @NelsonGon - try pycharm - it has a free community edition, is used by a large fraction of python developers and in my opinion it is the best out there

Comment: I usually use Emacs with elpy, but I would not recommend that if you do not want to spend 3 months just to understand how to properly open it ;) Multiple IDE are used around me, like PyCharm, vim, jupyter, ... A search engine can probably help you more than me.

Comment: I have PyCharm but couldn't get it to help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281190/pycharm-imports-and-code-completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variables T and F as such and they will represent the corresponding boolean throughout the code `T, F = [True, False]`.

I think this would be considered bad practice though. Better to be explicit in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `var` first:

```
import seaborn as sns
F = False

iris=sns.load_dataset("iris")
iris.groupby("species").size().sort_values(ascending=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variable 'F' and assign 'False' to it. As it suggested in other answers. But this is not a good practice. "Readability counts", refer to:

```
import this
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.